# Two different Facebook domains?

Tags: facebook

Today I realized that when I entered `facbook.com` in the domain bar in my browser, it loaded up the domain `facebook.com/?_rdr`. But when I removed this `?_rdr` part, the same page was loaded again. I was just wondering what this means? Or is this something that I don't know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably means that Facebook bought some (or all) domains that are similar to `facebook.com`, in order to avoid phishing schemes and the likes. (Just as `facebook.co` does the same thing.) It’s a form of brand (and traffic etc.) protection.

Answer (score 3):

As Alex said it's to avoid phishing. However, always check if the URL is correct and the protocol is HTTPS when navigating on Facebook. The SSL certificate of a phishing Facebook site (for instance with a domain that looks like) would not be valid or the protocol wouldn't be HTTPS.

Also, the `?_rdr` part is PHP stuff (GET request). It probably gives Facebook some informations about the redirection or the domain you come from.
More infos of PHP GET here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm